# Babies - are we talking about their birth, arrival or delivery?

Tags: word-request

What is the right word here?

> Traditionally, fathers usually give names to their babies after 3 days of their **birth\arrival\delivery**.

Comment: FYI, the correct character for separating alternative options is the forward slash (`/`), not the backslash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Traditionally, fathers usually give names to their babies 3 days **after their birth**.

Of those three, *birth* sounds most natural; babies don't arrive and [delivery](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/delivering) describes what the mother does (or the doctor/nurse), not the baby, who is *being* born, so an alternative would be

> Traditionally, fathers usually give names to their babies 3 days **after they're born**.

Note that I've changed the word order for 'after' as well, the 'after' ... 'of' construction is only used when describing a prolonged event, e.g. "After 3 days of marching we reached the camp."

Also, I think you can drop the "usually", since it's already implied by "traditionally".

Comment: I would say delivery describes what the *doctor* does...

Comment: @HostileFork you're right, that can be both the mother and the doctor; I hadn't considered the latter option.

Answer (score 1):

I would change to

> Babies are traditionally named by their fathers when they are 3 days old

Although this can lead to ambiguity as to who is 3 days old in the sentence, it would be natural to assume the subject is the baby being named and not the father who is 3 days old.

Comment: Beside the point, but it's better style to avoid the passive voice, i.e. "*Fathers traditionally name their babies* when they are 3 days old."